# Passing an address in a function 2D DMA

Tags: c, stm32, dma

I have a function which has that prototype:

```
HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_DMA2D_Start(DMA2D_HandleTypeDef *hdma2d, uint32_t pdata, uint32_t DstAddress, uint32_t Width,  uint32_t Height)
```

It should draw a pixel onto the framebuffer

```
HAL_DMA2D_Start(&hdma2d, c,
                &OLED_BUFFER[0] +
                    (PIXELWINDOW.pos.x + PIXELWINDOW.pos.y * 320) * 2,
                1, 1);
```

the problem with that line

```
 &OLED_BUFFER[0] +
                        (PIXELWINDOW.pos.x + PIXELWINDOW.pos.y * 320) * 2
```

I get that warning

```
warning: passing argument 3 of 'HAL_DMA2D_Start' makes integer from pointer without a cast
```

OLED_BUFFER is an array of type uint16_t it's 2 bytes per pixel framebuffer

Here is the full function:

```
void PIXELDATA(uint16_t c) {
  DMA2D_HandleTypeDef hdma2d;
  hdma2d.Instance = DMA2D;
  hdma2d.Init.Mode = DMA2D_R2M;
  hdma2d.Init.ColorMode = DMA2D_OUTPUT_RGB565;
  hdma2d.Init.OutputOffset = 320 - 1;
  HAL_DMA2D_Init(&hdma2d);
  if (PIXELWINDOW.pos.x <= PIXELWINDOW.end.x &&

      PIXELWINDOW.pos.y <= PIXELWINDOW.end.y) {
    HAL_DMA2D_Start(&hdma2d, c,
                    (uint16_t)&OLED_BUFFER +
                        (PIXELWINDOW.pos.x + PIXELWINDOW.pos.y * 320) * 2,
                    1, 1);
    HAL_DMA2D_PollForTransfer(&hdma2d, 10);

  }
  PIXELWINDOW.pos.x++;

  if (PIXELWINDOW.pos.x > PIXELWINDOW.end.x) {
    PIXELWINDOW.pos.x = PIXELWINDOW.start.x;

    PIXELWINDOW.pos.y++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you adding `(PIXELWINDOW.pos.x + PIXELWINDOW.pos.y * 320) * 2` to the address of the function?

Comment: @awakened so how would I draw a single pixel then ? X + Y *Width to move to the x,y coordinate ? What's your suggestion to fix it ?

Comment: I am sorry. I misread the question. Do you want to change a pixel at a particular `(x,y)` location in `OLED_BUFFER`?

Comment: @awakened Yes to draw a pixel on that framebuffer using DMA2D

Comment: @awakened I posted the full function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third parameter of the function `HAL_DMA2D_Start` is not a pointer but an integer, more precisely a `uint32_t`. So you must cast `&OLED_BUFFER[0] + ...` to a 32 bits unsigned integer.

Note that on a 32 bits STM32, a pointer and a `uint32_t` are both 32 bits variables, but it is not always the case on other processors.

In my opinion it would be cleaner that the function `HAL_DMA2D_Start` takes a pointer as parameter, or a `uintptr_t`.